# Проблема с совмещением страниц Login и Register в Identity Net Core из-за свойств [BindProperty] и [Required]

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-identity-2, required

Появилась необходимость совместить 2 страницы *Identity*: **Login** и **Register**, поместив их на одной странице.

За основу была взята страница **Login**. В неё вписал функционал **Register**. После всех преобразований получилось следующее

**Login.cshtml**
...

```
<div class="form-container sign-up-container">
   <form asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" asp-page-handler="register" method="post">
      <h1>Регистрация</h1>
      <span class="title-span">Заполните все указанные ниже поля</span>
      <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <input asp-for="RegisterVModel.Password" class="inputText form-control" required/>
         <span class="floating-label">Пароль</span>
         <span asp-validation-for="RegisterVModel.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <input asp-for="RegisterVModel.ConfirmPassword" class="inputText form-control" required/>
         <span class="floating-label">Подтверждение пароля</span>
         <span asp-validation-for="RegisterVModel.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <input asp-for="RegisterVModel.Email" class="inputText form-control" required/>
         <span class="floating-label">Адрес ведомственной электронной почты</span>
         <span asp-validation-for="RegisterVModel.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Регистрация</button>
   </form>
</div>
<div class="form-container sign-in-container">
   <form asp-page-handler="login" method="post">
      <h1>Выполнить вход</h1>
      <span class="title-span">Укажите свой логин и пароль для входа</span>
      <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <input asp-for="LoginVModel.UserName" class="inputText form-control" required/>
         <span class="floating-label">Имя пользователя</span>
         <span asp-validation-for="LoginVModel.UserName" class="text-danger" style="font-size:7px"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <input asp-for="LoginVModel.Password" class="inputText form-control" required/>
         <span class="floating-label">Пароль</span>
         <span asp-validation-for="LoginVModel.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
         <label asp-for="LoginVModel.RememberMe">
            <input asp-for="LoginVModel.RememberMe" style="width: auto;"/>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LoginVModel.RememberMe)
         </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Войти</button>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <p>
            <a href="#">Забыли свой пароль?</a>
         </p>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

...

**Login.cshtml.cs**
...

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

    public LoginModel(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, 
        ILogger<LoginModel> logger,
        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public LoginViewModel LoginVModel { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public RegisterViewModel RegisterVModel { get; set; }

    public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    [TempData]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public class LoginViewModel
    {
        
        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле <b>{0}</b> обязательно для ввода")]
        [Display(Name = "Имя пользователя", Prompt = "Имя пользователя")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле <b>{0}</b> обязательно для ввода")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Пароль", Prompt = "Пароль")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Запомнить меня?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле <b>{0}</b> обязательно для ввода")]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Значение поля <b>{0}</b> должно содержать не менее <b>{2}</b> символов.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Пароль", Prompt = "Пароль")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Подтверждение пароля", Prompt = "Подтверждение пароля")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Пароль и его подтверждение не совпадают.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле <b>{0}</b> обязательно для ввода")]
        [Display(Name = "Адрес электронной почты", Prompt = "Адрес электронной почты")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    public async Task OnGetLoginAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ...
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostLoginAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
    
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ...
        }
        return Page();
    }

    public async Task OnGetRegisterAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ...
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostRegisterAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ...
        }

        return Page();
    }
}
```

...

Проблема возникает в том, что от пользователя требуется либо зарегистрироваться, либо авторизоваться.
Но проблема в том, что **[BindProperty]**

```
[BindProperty]
public LoginViewModel LoginVModel { get; set; }

[BindProperty]
public RegisterViewModel RegisterVModel { get; set; }
```

проверяет обо класса и у полей, которых есть свойство **[Required()]**.
Это приводит к тому, что пользователю нужно заполнять все поля в области регистрации и авторизации, у которых есть свойство **[Required()]**, чтобы выполнить регистрацию или войти в систему. Если убрать **[Required()]**, то всё работает, и валидация за счёт ***jquery.validate.js*** в **Identity** проходит. Но хотелось бы решить эту проблему так, чтобы и **[Required()]** можно было использовать. Как это сделать

Comment: Вопрос выглядит как "можно ли обязательное поле сделать необязательным, но при этом чтобы оно оставалось обязательным". Нет, это так не работает. Ищите другой способ.

Comment: Например найдите способ сабмитить форму в разные урлы в зависимости от того, какое дейстрие выполняет пользователь. Для сервера это должны быть 2 разных действия как если бы это были 2 разные формы. Все фокусы надо реализовать на фронте.